# tree.nodeSize in d3 v4

Tags: algorithm, d3.js, svg, tree

I use  d3.tree().nodeSize() to Calculate the coordinates，but I see the cousin's distance is twice that of the brothers.see the Image
[image: describe of distance]
I want the distance to be consistent.I did not see how to solve in the api,How to deal with it?

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height"),
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(40,200)");

var tree = d3.tree()
    .nodeSize([50,50]);//make node space
var data={
    id:1,
    children:[
     {
      id:2,
      children:[
         {
          id:3
         },
         {
          id:4
         }  
      ]
     },
     {
      id:5,
      children:[
        {id:6},
        {id:7}
      ]
     }
    ]
};
var root=d3.hierarchy(data)
tree(root)
//console.log(root)
var link = g.selectAll(".link")
      .data(root.descendants().slice(1))
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", diagonal).style("fill","none").style("stroke-width",1).style("stroke","#000000");

  var node = g.selectAll(".node")
      .data(root.descendants())
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", function(d) { return "node" + (d.children ? " node--internal" : " node--leaf"); })
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });// add node

  node.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 2.5);

  node.append("text")
      .attr("dy", 3)
      .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children ? -8 : 8; })
      .style("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children ? "end" : "start"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.id; });
function diagonal(d) {
  return "M" + d.y + "," + d.x
      + "L" + d.parent.y + "," + d.parent.x;
}
```

```html
<svg width="960" height="2400"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

recently I  see `tree.separation` to deal this problem

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height"),
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(40,200)");

var tree = d3.tree()
    .nodeSize([50,50])//make node space
    .separation(function(a,b){
        return a.parrent==b.parrent?1:1
    });// make separation accessor 1
var data={
    id:1,
    children:[
     {
      id:2,
      children:[
         {
          id:3
         },
         {
          id:4
         }  
      ]
     },
     {
      id:5,
      children:[
        {id:6},
        {id:7}
      ]
     }
    ]
};
var root=d3.hierarchy(data)
tree(root)
//console.log(root)
var link = g.selectAll(".link")
      .data(root.descendants().slice(1))
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", diagonal).style("fill","none").style("stroke-width",1).style("stroke","#000000");

  var node = g.selectAll(".node")
      .data(root.descendants())
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", function(d) { return "node" + (d.children ? " node--internal" : " node--leaf"); })
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });// add node

  node.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 2.5);

  node.append("text")
      .attr("dy", 3)
      .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children ? -8 : 8; })
      .style("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children ? "end" : "start"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.id; });
function diagonal(d) {
  return "M" + d.y + "," + d.x
      + "L" + d.parent.y + "," + d.parent.x;
}
```

```html
<svg width="960" height="2400"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`return a.parrent==b.parrent?1:1`

doesn't do anything.

You should use `return a.parrent==b.parrent?1:2` or just `return 1`